# Subfloats labeling

Tags: positioning, subfloats, labels

I'm working on a figure containing 30 figs, 5 rows 6 cols. What I want to do is: in the begining of every row of figure i want to write some text but i want it to be written vertical not horizontal. For the columns I want to write a text and group it for each two columns, so for example on the top of column 1 & 2 write data1 which will be centered between the 2 columns. This is really difficult for me.

This figure explains what I want to do where I want to put text in the red markers

[image: desired]

This is a sample of my code:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\caption{aaa}
\label{fig:rulascore}
\end{figure*}
```

update:

I've updated my code "below" but nothing is appearing as shown in this pic [image: update]

code used:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image11) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image12) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image13) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image14) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_entropy}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image15) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image16) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_entropy}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image21) 
  {\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_entropy}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_no_of_levels}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_entropy}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_no_of_levels}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 7cm, clip=true,width=.15\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/interference/1500/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1500mm_with_interference_distance_1100-pgms_entropy}}
\caption{aaa}
\label{fig:rulascore}
\end{figure*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[above] at ( $ (image11.north)!0.5!(image12.north) $ ) {some text goes here};
\node[above] at ( $ (image13.north)!0.5!(image14.north) $ ) {some text goes here};
\node[above] at ( $ (image15.north)!0.5!(image16.north) $ ) {some text goes here};
\node[rotate=90,yshift=10pt] at (image11.west) {some text};
\node[rotate=90,yshift=10pt] at (image21.west) {some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); the idea is to place each figure of the first row and of the first column inside a named node, and then to use these nodes to place the texts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image11) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image12) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image13) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image14) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image15) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image16) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image21) 
  {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\caption{aaa}
\label{fig:rulascore}
\end{figure*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[above] at ( $ (image11.north)!0.5!(image12.north) $ ) {some text goes here};
\node[above] at ( $ (image13.north)!0.5!(image14.north) $ ) {some text goes here};
\node[above] at ( $ (image15.north)!0.5!(image16.north) $ ) {some text goes here};
\node[rotate=90,yshift=10pt] at (image11.west) {some text};
\node[rotate=90,yshift=10pt] at (image21.west) {some text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Not directly related to the question, but your images were too wide for the text area width (or are you perhaps using writing a two-column document?); in any case, I changed the width from `0.33\linewidth` to `0.15\textwidth` and used `\hfill` to evenly separate the figures in each row (of course, you can revert these changes). Also, the option `[t]` for `figure` might be too restrictive; I suppressed it from my example.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing appearing. I've updated the question with the code i used and a pic explaining the results.

Comment: @user1460166 Are you getting any error messages at all? (I suppose it's possible `graphicx` isn't installed.)

Comment: Just an update [from chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8318) - this code works for me.

Comment: Another update: move the second tikz picture back inside the figure environment so it floats with everything else (things can get weird)